# Could not AOT assembly - When building Xamarin Android project using MSBUILD on Windows

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, msbuild, azure-devops

I am building a `Xamarin.Android` in release mode using an automated build using `Azure DevOps`

I have `AOT` turned on with `LLVM` turned on (I know previously AOT was "Experimental" but I think its not production ready)

I can build my project locally but when using MSBuild I get the following errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly:
>   System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly:
>   Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Android.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly:
>   CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: Syncfusion.Core.XForms.dll
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: Plugin.Messaging.dll
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly:
>   Syncfusion.DocIORenderer.Portable.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly:
>   SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly:
>   Syncfusion.DataSource.Portable.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly:
>   Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics.Android.Bindings.dll C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: Plugin.CurrentActivity.dll
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2730,3):
>   Error XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: SQLite-net.dll

The crux of this error is:

> Could not AOT the assembly: AssemblyX.dll

I have tried building on a hosted VM too and I get the same error.

So where does the root cause of this error lie, is it **Visual Studio? Xamarin? The Individual Libraries or My Project?**

Comment: Turn on diagnostic level debugging for MSBuild, clean/rebuild and post the full AOT build error.

Comment: @SushiHangover I have uploaded the build log here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/be3d6fe1ad9127882ea0cbddb6b0d0f420190214171202/491c1b where `debug` has been specified for MSBuild

Comment: Looks linked to this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be just one assembly causing the error:

> System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll V4.5.0

Found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/4.5.0

After refactoring that library out my solution built fine.

You can track this issue here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2751